# Any ways to execute Action/Command After ExecReload in systemd?

Tags: systemd

I need to create service that can notify me by slack message whenever the service is reloaded using `ExecReload` in systemd.

So, I've read about `ExecStartPost` & `ExecStopPost`, any direction similiar to a reload action after `ExecReload` executed ?

I know I can just use `&&` after the reload command `ExecReload`, but is there any other way around?

Comment: No. Why do you want to do that

Comment: For monitoring purpose I think, my apps behave differently when its reloaded so I need to keep track if its reloaded

Comment: Why doesn't `systemctl status ` satisfy your needs?